# update_post_meta, xml parser

Tags: wp-insert-post, post-meta, xml

I'm hitting the wall for nearly two hours now, trying to figure this out.

Here is the thing' I have made a xml parser to read xml file and add posts (with content) from xml:

```
$ch = curl_init( "http://abc.xml" );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
$data = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
$doc = new SimpleXmlElement( $data, LIBXML_NOCDATA );


$size = count( $doc );
$count_added = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++ )
{
    $img = $doc->prod[$i]->awImage;
    // skipping the part of post adding
    $my_post_id = wp_insert_post( $new_post );
    update_post_meta( $my_post_id, 'prod_image', $img );
}
```

Problem is that custom filed doesn't get my `$img` value, even though if I do echo `$img` - I get the content... Strange thing is if I create some other variable `$var="test"` and enter this instead `$img` in `update_post_meta` - the custom field gets the value of `$test`...

Whats wrong here, because I'm starting to hit keyboard really badly...

Regards.

Comment: Have you tried to set _$img_ variable directly (I mean write it down by hand) to "$doc->prod[$i]->awImage" content and check if it is stored?

Comment: You should also check if the post ID isn't already present, when inserting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you use `add_post_meta` instead, because `update_post_meta` assumes that you have already that value and you are updating it ( from http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta ).

Also check if `$doc->prod[$i]->awImage` is actually a string (do `print_r` instead of `echo`).

Comment: If a value isn't found, update_post_meta will insert it. "The first thing this function will do is make sure that `$meta_key` already exists on $post_id. If it does not, `add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value)` is called instead and its result is returned."  From the codex page you linked to.

Comment: Fair enough, maybe it's the loop value... what if dumps `print_r($doc)` to see if the problem is there?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of print_r. the thing was this var was somehow SimpleXMLElement object and wordpress had problems with that, so what i did was - $img=strval($img); to return string from this value.